# How to Redirect a custome page after user login successful in PeopleSoft

Tags: authentication, redirect, peoplesoft

How to redirect a custome  page as soon as login successfully by Single sign on?

Now the peopleSoft Server can Authentication user:

```
SetAuthenticationResult(True, &oprid, "", False)
```

if true, but I don’t know redirect point page.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform this in two ways:

1st - Have a direct link to the page, in the format `http://yourserver:port/psp/environment/EMPLOYEE/yournode/c/MENU.COMPONENT.MARKET`
after the successful login, he will land in this page

2nd - Make the user lands custom page, and then transfer him from this page (you could place the code on page activate).

Answer (score 0):

The most correct way to do this would be to use custom homepage tabs that have a lower sequence number (executed first).

We do this at The University of Texas System.  We have 2 portals, EMPLOYEE & STUDENT, we want users to go to a single link then get forwarded to the correct homepage based on role assignment.

The user starts at a link like:
https://my.utsystem.edu/psp/UTSDEV/?cmd=start
or
https://my.utsystem.edu/psp/UTSDEV/?cmd=login

Once they login it defaults to the EMPLOYEE portal, as it is configured as our default portal. Next it will go to the first homepage tab the user has access to.  So if the user has a STUDENT role they have access to this custom homepage tab that has embedded javascript that will redirect them to the STUDENT portal.

Comment: thanks Jared ,which by the way,Did you develop a mobile Application based PeopleSoft System

Comment: We have wrapped the portal objects (pagelets, header, footer, menu, etc) with Bootstrap grid and other components.   It renders really nice on mobile.